# Why doesn't htmlspecialchars work inside a function?

Tags: php

I have a very simple php script designed to test the function htmlspecialchars:

```
$question="<script>alert('hacked')</script>";

echo "<br>original question=",$question;

$question = make_secure( $question );

echo "<br>converted question=",$question;     

echo "<br>converted question calling htmlspecialchars=",htmlspecialchars($question);

function make_secure($data)  {
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);     return $data;  }
```

It should remove the special chars from the original string $question by calling a function with htmlspecialchars inside it. However, the function does not seem remove the special chars. They are only removed if I call htmlspecialchars explicitly in the script. Why?

Thanks.

EDIT: This is what I see when I run the script:

```
original question=
converted question=<script>alert('hacked')</script>
converted question calling htmlspecialchars=&lt;script&gt;alert('hacked')&lt;/script&gt;
```

(the 'hacked' script is also executed first). To rephrase my question, why is the script still perfectly visible in `$question` on line line `converted question=` ? i.e. why hasn't the variable been converted? I thought that after the variable had been converted, the script should no longer be visible.

Comment: Have you tried not having the same name as a function argument and variable? eg `make_secure($str){ return htmlspecialchars($str); }`

Comment: Works as expected for me. http://3v4l.org/sHIE6

Comment: Works as expected for me, as well.

Comment: You’re overwriting `$question` with the return value of `make_secure($question)` so the result of the latter `htmlspecialchars($question)` is distorted. However, `make_secure($question) === htmlspecialchars($question)` should yield true.

Comment: Despite the fact that you override already encoded $question with the result of htmlspecialchars (rendering this example pointless), it should work.

Comment: (1) Yes I've tried not having the same name for a function argument and variable, but that didn't help.

Comment: (2) I realize the result of the 2nd is distorted, what I don't understand is why the script is still in the variable after it has been passed to the make_secure function

Comment: I've edited the question to show you what I get when I run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output visible to the user should be:

```
(nothing, script executed)
<script>alert('hacked')</script>
&lt;script&gt;alert('hacked')&lt;/script&gt;
```

The *actual* output, visible to the browser is:

```
<script>alert('hacked')</script>
&lt;script&gt;alert('hacked')&lt;/script&gt;
&amp;lt;script&amp;gt;alert('hacked')&amp;lt;/script&amp;gt;
```

Which is exactly correct. The first line is unescaped, the HTML and script get interpreted. The second line is escaped once, displaying the text as is to the user. The third line is escaped twice, displaying the text as escaped once to the user.

You keep escaping the same variable over and over, so the result is going to change depending on how often you escape it. Maybe start here: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Thanks, I understand now from your link that php is just interpreting the escaped characters when it is outputting the converted `$output` to the screen :)

Comment: PHP is not interpreting anything, *the browser* is.